# Pinch to zoom respecting pinch location (Like in Safari)

Tags: ios, math, nsarray, core-plot, pinchzoom

So I effectively have a image I'd like to zoom horizontally but also be able to respect the location of the pinch. So if you pinched on the left, It'd zoom into the left. Ideally, the points where you pinch would stay with your fingers.

My case is a little more specific, I'm plotting data on a graph, so I instead will be manipulating an array of data and taking a subset. However, I'm sure the math is similar. (BUT, I can't just use an Affinetransform as most examples I've found does)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using core-plot for iOS (http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)?

Comment: yup... the default pinchzoom stuff seems to zoom my whole graph (like the whole axes! I just want to zoom the x axis, but more so the data on it... as the grand plan is to have clustered data turn into more raw data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default pinch gesture handler scales the graph around the point of the gesture. Use a plot space delegate to limit the scaling to only one axis.

Comment: But doesn't that just zoom the graph, not actually redraw it?

Comment: It redraws the graph as you zoom.

Comment: so implement `- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint` and then do what?

Comment: But yeah, this is more of a zoom than a data manipulation. Ideally, The data x axis would redraw with more minor/major points as required.

Comment: A better delegate method for limiting the zoom to a single axis is `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:`. In addition to adjusting the plot range, you can also update the axis labeling properties in the delegate as the range changes.

Comment: Is it normal for the y-axis (the physical points) to come along for the scaling ride?

Comment: Yes. Use a delegate to alter that behavior if you want it to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a UIScrollView? As far as I know, you'll get this behaviour for free.

Comment: Nope - I dont. I'm using [CorePlot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) to plot data. So trying to zoom in on a array really, so need to find the new start index and the new length so I can call `subarrayWithRange` on my array.

Answer (score 0):

I built the below solution for standard `UIView`s where `UIScrollView` and `CGAffineTransform` zooms were not appropriate as I did not want the view's subviews to be skewed. I’ve also used it with a CorePlot line graph.

The zooming is centred on the point where the user starts the pinch.

Here’s a simple implementation:

```
@interface BMViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat pinchXCoord; // The point at which the pinch occurs
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat minZoomProportion; // The minimum zoom proportion allowed. Used to control minimum view width
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat viewCurrentXPosition; // The view-to-zoom’s frame’s current origin.x value.
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat originalViewWidth, viewCurrentWidth; // original and current frame width of the view.

@end

@implementation BMViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup the pinch gesture recognizer
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchZoomRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchZoomGestureDetected:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchZoomRecognizer];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.originalViewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.viewCurrentWidth = self.originalViewWidth;
}

- (void)pinchZoomGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint pinchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.viewCurrentWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        self.viewCurrentXPosition = self.view.frame.origin.x;

        // Set the pinch X coordinate to a point relative to the bounds of the view
        self.pinchXCoord = pinchLocation.x - self.viewCurrentXPosition;
        self.minZoomProportion = self.originalViewWidth / self.viewCurrentWidth;
    }

    CGFloat proportion = recognizer.scale;
    CGFloat width = self.viewCurrentWidth * MAX(proportion, self.minZoomProportion); // Set a minimum zoom width (the original size)
    width = MIN(self.originalViewWidth * 4, width); // Set a maximum zoom width (original * 4)
    CGFloat rawX = self.viewCurrentXPosition + ((self.viewCurrentWidth - width) * (self.pinchXCoord / self.viewCurrentWidth)); // Calculate the new X value
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    CGFloat newXValue = MIN(rawX, 0); // Don't let the view move too far right
    newXValue = MAX(newXValue, self.originalViewWidth - width); // Don't let the view move too far left
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(newXValue, frame.origin.y, width, frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"newXValue: %f, width: %f", newXValue, width);
}

@end
```

This is all that needs to be done to resize the horizontal axis of a `UIView`.

For Core-Plot, it is assumed the `CPTGraphHostingView` is a subview of the `UIViewController`’s view being resized. The `CPTGraphHostingView` is redrawn when its frame/bounds are changed so, in the `layoutSubviews` method of the containing view change the `CPTGraphHostingView` and plot area’s frame’s relative to the bounds of its parent (which is the view you should be resizing). Something like this:

```
self.graphHostingView.frame = self.bounds;
self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame.frame = self.bounds;
```

I haven’t attempted to change data on the graph as it zooms, but I can’t imagine it would be too difficult. In `layoutSubviews` on your containing view, call `reloadData` on your `CPTGraph`.